# Can't find variable: angular (PhantomJS webcrawler)

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs

Hi so I'm trying to write a webcrawler type script in PhantomJS.

Here is the code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onCallback = function() {
   page.render('snapshot.png');
   phantom.exit();
};
page.open('http://somesitewithangularscripts.com');
```

However it keeps on giving me the error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
```

From what I read online I need to tell phantom where the angular library is on my local machine? But I can't find any guides/docs/tutorials on how to do that.

By the way I'm running everything via an npm framework on my machine.

PhantomJs version: 1.9.8

Error msg:

```
Unable to load resource (#19URL:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#22URL:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#39URL:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#40URL:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.min.js)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#41URL:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-animate.min.js)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#42URL:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#43URL:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-cookies.min.js)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
TRACE:
 -> http://na.lolesports.com/profiles/lolesports_profile/modules/custom/esports/esports_directives/js/ngModules.js?nu5xd5: 63
 -> http://na.lolesports.com/profiles/lolesports_profile/modules/custom/esports/esports_directives/js/ngModules.js?nu5xd5: 66
ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
TRACE:
 -> http://na.lolesports.com/sites/all/libraries/angular-truncate/src/truncate.js?nu5xd5: 1
ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
TRACE:
 -> http://na.lolesports.com/sites/all/libraries/angular-timer/angular-timer.min.js?nu5xd5: 8
ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
TRACE:
 -> http://na.lolesports.com/profiles/lolesports_profile/modules/custom/esports/esports_directives/js/esportsDirectives.js?nu5xd5: 8
ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
TRACE:
 -> http://na.lolesports.com/profiles/lolesports_profile/modules/custom/esports/esports_directives/js/filters/esportsFilters.js?nu5xd5: 3
ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
TRACE:
 -> http://na.lolesports.com/profiles/lolesports_profile/modules/custom/esports/esports_directives/js/esportsServices.js?nu5xd5: 8
ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
TRACE:
 -> http://na.lolesports.com/profiles/lolesports_profile/modules/custom/esports/js/esportsApp.js?nu5xd5: 8
ERROR: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'esportsDirectives.controller')
TRACE:
 -> http://na.lolesports.com/profiles/lolesports_profile/modules/custom/esports/esports_directives/js/controllers/MatchController.js?nu5xd5: 6
Unable to load resource (#111URL:https://cdn.leagueoflegends.com/riotbar/prod/1.5.2/images/bar/bg-bar.jpg?1435084967)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#112URL:https://cdn.leagueoflegends.com/riotbar/prod/1.5.2/images/bar/icon-game-lol.png?1435084967)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#113URL:https://cdn.leagueoflegends.com/riotbar/prod/1.5.2/images/account/sprites-sacb8a8a753.png)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#114URL:https://cdn.leagueoflegends.com/riotbar/prod/1.5.2/images/bar/dropdown-trigger-blue.png?1435084967)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
Unable to load resource (#152URL:https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?t=dc&aip=1&_r=3&v=1&_v=j38&tid=UA-37673467-1&cid=123674724.1441623986&jid=1834200343&_u=SGAAgAQi~&z=790116041)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
CONSOLE: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-2/html/container.html from frame with URL http://na.lolesports.com/na-lcs/2015/spring/matches/week-1/team-solomid-vs-cloud9. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
 (from line #undefined in "undefined")
CONSOLE: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-2/html/container.html from frame with URL http://na.lolesports.com/na-lcs/2015/spring/matches/week-1/team-solomid-vs-cloud9. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
 (from line #undefined in "undefined")
CONSOLE: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-2/html/container.html from frame with URL http://na.lolesports.com/na-lcs/2015/spring/matches/week-1/team-solomid-vs-cloud9. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
 (from line #undefined in "undefined")
Unable to load resource (#153URL:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)
Error code: 6. Description: SSL handshake failed
```

Comment: (1) What PhantomJS version do you have? (2) Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors. (3) If the page doesn't execute `window.callPhantom()` then you won't see anything. I think you wanted to register to `onLoadFinished` instead of `onCallback`.

Comment: hmm i don't think the page executes window.callPhantom(). Since I'm simply trying to scrape a site.

Also the error seems to be not being able to load resources:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js
etc etc

Comment: Try running PhantomJS with `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` (and maybe `--ssl-protocol=any`): `phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any script.js`